# Convert date to Unix time (seconds since 1970)

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert a user-provided date to a value of seconds since 1970.

For example, if my app is provided with the date, `5-MAY-2011 00:00:00 +0000`, then I want the timestamp `1304553600` (the number of seconds between that date and January 1, 1970).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume your date is a valid date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateF setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle]; //this format will be according to your own.

NSDate *todayDate = [dateF dateFromString: @"5-MAY-2011 00:00:00 +0000"]; //please note, this date format must match the NSDateFormatter Style, or else return null.

NSTimeInterval inter = [todayDate timeIntervalSince1970]; //return as double
```

For more information please refer to this [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) and the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is given method for NSDate class. see this

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970
```

it returns you seconds (what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Use a NSDateFormatter to parse the date string into an actual NSDate object, and then call the [-timeIntervalSince1970](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSince1970) method on that object to get the number that you're looking for.